# karma problems while trying to set up an AngularJS-Testing-Article

Tags: karma-runner

I tried to set up AngularJS-Testing-Article project with below command

git clone git://github.com/yearofmoo-articles/AngularJS-Testing-Article.git
cd AngularJS-Testing-Article
npm install

It caught below npm installation error and look like it depends on Karma@0.12.8. But also check with Karma version under project directory './node_modules/karma/bin' with command 'karma --version', it prompt 'Karma version: 0.12.24'.

Does anyone know on how to remediate it.

```
44170 error node v0.10.32
44171 error npm  v2.1.2
44172 error code EPEERINVALID
44173 error peerinvalid The package karma does not satisfy its siblings' peerDependencies requirements!
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-mocha@0.1.9 wants karma@>=0.12.8
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-chrome-launcher@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9.3
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-safari-launcher@0.1.1 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-firefox-launcher@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-ng-scenario@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-script-launcher@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-html2js-preprocessor@0.1.0 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-jasmine@0.1.5 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-requirejs@0.2.2 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-coffee-preprocessor@0.1.3 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer karma-phantomjs-launcher@0.1.4 wants karma@>=0.9
44173 error peerinvalid Peer grunt-karma@0.7.1 wants karma@~0.10.0
44174 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: grunt-karma wants karma 0.10.x, you should submit an issue on github. I think grunt-karma is outdated.